# Get an actual substring with Regex in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this pattern

`@"($\w+)"`

And it will successfuly catch for example `$substring` inside `long text $substring the rest of the text`.

But it will fail in certain scenarios, for example `some string $sub.string the rest of string` will only return `$sub`

What can I do to get an actual full substring from the string?

Comment: You probably have `@"\$\w+"`, and you want `\$\S+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you post full reply I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\$\S+
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%24%5CS%2B&i=some%20string%20%24sub.string%20the%20rest%20of%20string%20%24mo-re.he%2Fre).

**NOTE**: If you want to get rid of any trailing punctuation (other than `_`) you may add `\b` at the end, `\$\S+\b`.

*Details*:

- `\$` - a `$` char (needs escaping since `$` is a special metacharacter asserting end of string position)
- `\S+` - any one or more non-whitespace chars.

In C#, you can use

```cs
var output = Regex.Matches(text, @"\$\S+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```